scheduling a local notification in capacitor v4 angular by receiving a response from listening to a websocket message while app is in background
So I have an angular android capacitor v4 application and when my user goes out of the app, my app successfully keeps on listening for their location change through a plugin I installed called "@capacitor-community/background-geolocation" and uses the data received to invoke a method on my Hub in .NET signalR.
My issue now comes when I'm trying to create a local notification ("@capacitor/local-notifications") while the app is in the background.
The user needs to first enter the app so that we start listening for their location and then they can leave the app without removing it from their recents. After this, since they keep on sending their location updates and I successfully process that location and send it to my server using SignalR hubs, at any time they can receive a message from the server.
So when they receive a message from the server, the local notification does not show (it is supposed to show immediately when the message is received), but instead shows when the user enters the app again. I have no idea why it is doing this and I have been trying.
If anyone has encountered such an issue, please assist.
This is the part where I listen for location updates in the background:
BackgroundGeolocation.addWatcher({
        backgroundMessage: "Cancel to prevent battery drain.",
        backgroundTitle: "Tracking You.",
        requestPermissions: true,
        stale: false,
        distanceFilter: 0
      }, (location, error) => {
        if (error) {
          // alert(error);
          if (error.code === "NOT_AUTHORIZED") {
            if (window.confirm(
                "This app needs your location, " +
                "but does not have permission.\n\n" +
                "Open settings now?"
            )) {
                BackgroundGeolocation.openSettings();
            }
          }
          return
        }
        // alert(`Latitude: ${location.latitude}\nLongitude: ${location.longitude}`);
        this.geolocationConnection.invoke("SendLocation", {
          latitude: location.latitude,
          longitude: location.longitude,
          heading: location.bearing,
        });
      });

This is where I listen for the message from the server and create the notification. When a message is received from the server, I believe this part runs but just doesn't show the notification until I come back on the app for some reason:
this.geolocationHub.geolocationConnection.on('messageFromServer', async (data: any) => {
          this.geolocationHub.newRequest(data.requestId).then((request) => {
            this.socketId = data.clientId;
            App.getState().then(state => {
              if(state.isActive) {
                // do something while app is in foreground
              }
              else this.triggerNotification(request, this.socketId);
            })
            
          }, (err) => {
            // generate toast alert
            this.toastController.create({
              message: 'Trip request failed',
              duration: 3000,
              color: 'danger',
            }).then((toast) => {
              toast.present();
            });
          });
      });

This is how I trigger the notification:
triggerNotification(request?: Request, socketId?: string) {
    LocalNotifications.createChannel({
      id: "New-Channel",
      name: "NewNotif",
      vibration: true,
      visibility: 1,
      lights: true,
      importance: 5
    });

    LocalNotifications.registerActionTypes({ 
      types: [
        {
          id: "accept",
          actions: [
            {
              id: "accepted",
              title: "Accept"
            },
            {
              id: "decline",
              title: "Decline"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    });

    LocalNotifications.addListener("localNotificationActionPerformed", async (event) => {
      if(event.actionId == "accepted") {
        // do something regarding accepting
      } else if(event.actionId == "decline") {
        // do something regarding the declining
      }
    });


      LocalNotifications.schedule({
        notifications: [
          {
            id: 1,
            channelId: "New-Channel",
            title: "New Notification",
            body: "Expand to view  details.",
            largeBody: `Testing...`,
            actionTypeId: "accept",
            ongoing: true
          }
        ]
      }).then(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          LocalNotifications.removeAllDeliveredNotifications();
        }, 20000)
      });
  }

